# Webserver with merged disks and backup optimal Solution

Tags: centos, hard-drive, hpe

I have to set up an HPE server GEN10 with 2x240GB SSD & 3x1.2TB HDDs as a webserver.

Client needs a production repo (live on apache folder), multiple development repos and backup.

My idea is 
1) merge the two SSDs into 1disk, so 1Disk with ~400GB total,
2) merge 2x1.2TB HDDs having all the development repos there
3) and 1.2TB backup by `rsync` the merged SSD.

Is there any issue with the above?  Do you think any other optimal solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I know you're new, and I'm trying to be nice here, but those are all terrible options sorry.

Firstly don't create a RAID 0/striped array for any data you care about - WHEN you lose one SSD you'll lose all your data, R0 has it's purpose, usually for holding data you don't mind losing like logs, but nobody uses it for professional work, nobody at all. Use RAID 1, if the space isn't enough buy larger.

Secondly are you considering using the third HDD as essentially a backup for the first and second? If so then that's a bad idea too - you shouldn't keep a backup on the same server, if someone hacked into your system they could delete the main data AND the backup, and your business is dead - backup to something else ok.
Also you just say 'merge' for your first and second HDD, again don't use R0 for this please, for the same reason as your SSDs, use R1/mirroring (or R10, R6 or R60), if you're wondering what to do with the third disk perhaps configure it as a hot-spare, that'll help when one of the disks dies.

You mention an optimal solution - Have your boot drive sized for what you want using a pair of SSDs of the right size, configured for R1, then also use R1 for your HDDs and backup somewhere else (btw rsync is great for this, just to another server).

One final thing, you say you have 250GB SSDs, I'm not sure HPE sell 250GB SSDs, tell me you're not using non-HPE disks please?!?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed I am new, and I trying to learn as fast as I can.  So, I'll do raid 1 on ssd (centos), raid 1 on 2 HDDs (all repos will be there), and the last hdd I will figure out what I am going to do with that.  All ssds are from HPE, indeed, the capacity is 240GB. my bad

Comment: Optimal solution for something that small as this machine is going virtual, sorry. This is 2019, not 1999.

Comment: @TomTom if you can give me some reference, I would be happy to check.  I don't know much, and im trying..